# npm: broken dependency

Tags: npm

I've added [this issue](https://github.com/cmer/parsley-payment/issues/1) on `parsley-payment` project. I'm getting an issue when I'm trying to install it:

> Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery-payment
>   'jquery-payment' is not in the npm registry.

I've took a look on npmjs repository and `jquery-payment` doesn't exist. Nevertheless, `jquery.payment` does.

As you can see, it's like a package dependency is broken (it's referencing to `jquery-payment` instead of `jquery.payment`).

Is there any work around it in order to be able to use it?

Comment: Sounds like the perfect opportunity for a PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no official way to override dependencies on your own project dependencies. Since it is an open source project, the most appropriate thing to do here is to fix the package.

1. Fork the [parsley-payment repository](https://github.com/cmer/parsley-payment);
2. Fix the project, preferably in a new branch. As you well diagnosed, it could be simply an issue with the name of one of the dependencies.
3. Create a Pull Request to the original repository with the suggested fix.

There is no need to wait for it to be accepted, though: In your project's package.json, redefine the dependency in question to point at the fixed version, using [Git URLs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) or [GitHub URLs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls):

```
"dependencies": {
   "parsley-payment": "YourUserName/parsley-payment#branch-with-fix"
}
```

This final step can be reverted once the fix is made upstream.

Comment: I looks like fine! Could you tell me how to build the url you have written betweem `""`?

Comment: If you look closely, you'll already see the pattern: "{githubUsername}/{repoName}#{branch}". Links to the documentation are in the answer as well.